# Ggplot2 - plotting 2 x geom_hlines() where x-axis is a categorical factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame `dm` which contains some numerical values `Activity`. We have target activities depending on several factors(Type, Weight). I am trying to plot for each categorical group ('Dose Protocol) the Stress and Rest (the 2 types) the distribution of Activity using geom_jitter. In addition to the geom_jitter, I would like to plot 2 x `geom_hlines` for each x-value (this is the target activity for stress and rest). This hline should cover only that DoseProtocol value instead of covering the entire x-axis. I have tried the following

```
 ggplot(dm, aes(x = factor(DoseProtocol, levels = dose_levels), y = Activity, color = Type)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), size = 2.5) +
  geom_hline(data = dm %>% filter(DRLType == "StressDRL"),
             aes(yintercept = DRL, color = Type), linetype = "solid") +
  geom_hline(data = dm %>% filter(DRLType == "RestDRL"),
             aes(yintercept = DRL, color = Type), linetype = "solid") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  labs(x = "Dose Protocol", y = "Activity (MBq)") +
  theme_bw()
```

This gives me the required 8 geom_hlines (4 factors, 2 types: stress/rest). However, each hline covers the entire x-axis. How can I adjust the plot so that the hline for factor1 only covers the jitter data for factor 1, etc

[image]

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 
108L, 108L, 109L, 109L, 11L, 11L, 110L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 
112L, 113L, 113L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 116L, 118L, 118L, 119L, 119L, 
12L, 12L, 121L, 121L, 122L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 13L, 13L, 131L, 
131L, 132L, 132L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 138L, 14L, 14L, 144L, 144L, 
145L, 145L, 146L, 146L, 147L, 147L, 148L, 148L, 153L, 153L, 154L, 
154L, 155L, 155L, 156L, 156L, 157L, 157L, 166L, 166L, 167L, 167L, 
184L, 184L, 185L, 185L, 186L, 186L, 187L, 187L, 195L, 195L, 196L, 
196L, 197L, 197L, 199L, 199L, 2L, 2L, 207L, 207L, 208L, 208L, 
209L, 209L, 210L, 210L, 211L, 211L, 212L, 212L, 215L, 215L, 216L, 
216L, 217L, 217L, 218L, 218L, 219L, 219L, 220L, 220L, 221L, 221L, 
222L, 222L, 223L, 223L, 224L, 224L, 225L, 225L, 226L, 226L, 228L, 
228L, 229L, 229L, 230L, 230L, 231L, 231L, 236L, 236L, 243L, 243L, 
249L, 249L, 250L, 250L, 251L, 251L, 252L, 252L, 254L, 254L, 255L, 
255L, 256L, 256L, 257L, 257L, 264L, 264L, 265L, 265L, 274L, 274L, 
275L, 275L, 278L, 278L, 279L, 279L, 282L, 282L, 283L, 283L, 284L, 
284L, 299L, 299L, 3L, 3L, 300L, 300L, 302L, 302L, 303L, 303L, 
306L, 306L, 307L, 307L, 308L, 308L, 309L, 309L, 31L, 31L, 317L, 
317L, 318L, 318L, 319L, 319L), weight = c(83, 83, 93, 93, 52, 
52, 93, 93, 71, 71, 71, 71, 82, 82, 125, 125, 125, 125, 118, 
118, 118, 118, 91, 91, 91, 91, 58, 58, 58, 58, 82, 82, 63, 63, 
63, 63, 52, 52, 71, 71, 122, 122, 122, 122, 70, 70, 70, 70, 71, 
71, 85, 85, 93, 93, 85, 85, 86, 86, 86, 86, 93, 93, 48, 48, 48, 
48, 91.5, 91.5, 91.5, 91.5, 94, 94, 94, 94, 74, 74, 74, 74, 106, 
106, 106, 106, 72, 72, 72, 72, 53, 53, 53, 53, 83, 83, 110, 110, 
110, 110, 53, 53, 53, 53, 101, 101, 101, 101, 59, 59, 59, 59, 
69, 69, 69, 69, 56, 56, 56, 56, 69, 69, 69, 69, 66, 66, 66, 66, 
57, 57, 57, 57, 77, 77, 77, 77, 99, 99, 99, 99, 54, 54, 87, 87, 
63, 63, 63, 63, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 74, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
75, 75, 75, 75, 74, 74, 74, 74, 68, 68, 68, 68, 77, 77, 77, 77, 
87, 87, 105, 105, 98, 98, 105, 105, 101, 101, 101, 101, 86, 86, 
86, 86, 77, 77, 77, 77, 90, 90, 73, 73, 73, 73, 67, 67), DoseProtocol = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Weight: 40 - 99.9kg", 
"Weight: 100 - 109.9kg", "Weight: 110 - 119.9kg", "Weight: >120kg"
), class = "factor"), DoseCode = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1), Type = c("Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", 
"Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", 
"Stress", "Rest", "Stress", "Rest", "Stress"), DRLType = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("StressDRL", "RestDRL"
), class = "factor"), DRL = c(600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 750, 250, 750, 250, 720, 240, 
720, 240, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 750, 250, 750, 250, 600, 200, 
600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 
600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 660, 220, 660, 220, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 720, 240, 720, 240, 600, 200, 
600, 200, 660, 220, 660, 220, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 
600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 
600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 660, 220, 
600, 200, 660, 220, 660, 220, 660, 220, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 
200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200, 600, 200), Activity = c(598, 
199, 607, 201, 574, 208, 607, 201, 514, 213, 514, 213, 577, 211, 
730, 260, 730, 260, 697, 245, 697, 245, 508, 210, 508, 210, 578, 
212, 578, 212, 577, 211, 600, 209, 600, 209, 574, 208, 587, 213, 
770, 248, 770, 248, 618, 205, 618, 205, 587, 213, 629, 226, 572, 
200, 629, 226, 580, 214, 580, 214, 572, 200, 600, 215, 600, 215, 
590, 207, 590, 207, 603, 203, 603, 203, 607, 205, 607, 205, 630, 
216, 630, 216, 606, 220, 606, 220, 585, 201, 585, 201, 598, 199, 
710, 230, 710, 230, 602, 202, 602, 202, 649, 237, 649, 237, 599, 
210, 599, 210, 605, 201, 605, 201, 601, 216, 601, 216, 586, 202, 
586, 202, 600, 200, 600, 200, 588, 204, 588, 204, 604, 211, 604, 
211, 580, 208, 580, 208, 596, 200, 619, 218, 603, 203, 603, 203, 
580, 211, 580, 211, 570, 207, 570, 207, 551, 214, 551, 214, 590, 
209, 590, 209, 579, 203, 579, 203, 594, 204, 594, 204, 613, 214, 
613, 214, 619, 218, 650, 235, 590, 190, 650, 235, 606, 234, 606, 
234, 580, 206, 580, 206, 62, 217, 62, 217, 607, 212, 600, 206, 
600, 206, 562, 199)), row.names = c(NA, 200L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add a zero-height `geom_errorbar`, where both ymin and ymax are the DRL value. You don't need to add different layers, since the grouping will be inferred by adding a color aesthetic to the layer:

```r
ggplot(dm, aes(x = factor(DoseProtocol, levels = dose_levels), 
               y = Activity, fill = Type)) +
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), size = 2.5, 
              alpha = 0.6, shape = 21, color = 'white') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = DRL, ymax = DRL, color = Type)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red3', 'blue3')) +
  labs(x = "Dose Protocol", y = "Activity (MBq)") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]